# How to Install OS without DVD and USB boot

Tags: remote-access

I just purchased a used Dell F1D 1U rack mount server and would like to install Ubuntu or ESXi with Virtual Disks or anything for that matter. I'v read that Dell's have built in DRAC so you can access it remotely. There are 3 ethernet plugs in the back but I dont know which one to use.

In the BIOS it says I can configure Remote access on [com1] or [com2] not sure if that is ethernet 1 & 2. I also set it up so to use a static IP adress.

Thats as far as I have gone. Not sure what to do next. I'v Tried to do a PXE server with TFTP but get stuck at Error "cant locate file" or something like that. Not even sure I want to go that route anymore because of all the hassel of editing files.

All my computers are OSX or Linux and the only Windows I have is via VMWare. What steps to i do now?

Comment: Since when did IT professionals (our target market) not know the difference between serial ports and ethernet ports ?

Comment: BTW: If you have the service tag of the Dell (As 7 letter and digit serial number) then you can go to the Dell site and check what hardware it is precisely. Including DRAC version.

Comment: Pretty sure the F1D is a custom build and not the normal Dell server range. I'd not make any assumptions about what that "should have" based on any other model of server from Dell.

Comment: Not a IT Pro. Just a Web Dev that wants to set up a development server and all around Backup Server.

Comment: I'm not without sympathy here (certainly wanting to set up a development machine is a good thing as opposed to developing in your production environment!), but we can't reasonably take you from zero to sysadmin on a Q&A site -- your best bet would be to work with your organization's existing systems staff to get this system up and running. If your organization has no existing systems staff write up your requirements (NOT your proposed solutions - just what you need) and bring in a contract admin for a few days to help you out.

Answer (score 7):

> I have read that Dell's have built in DRAC so you can access it remotely.

Dells have an option for a remote card. If you ordered on-line you usually get several options, varying from `no DRAC`, to `DRAC express` to `DRAC enterprise`. What is installed depends on which option you selected (or, if you did not change it, on what the default on the order form is).

[Edit] Or rather, I should say what the original buyer selected. I read over the "I bought a **used** Dell F1D".

> There are 3 Ethernet plugs in the back but I do not know which one to use.

How are they labeled? In the case of my Dell R300 the NICs were labeled
eth0 (second network card in the OS), eth1 (first network card in the OS) and DRAC.
That made it pretty clear which port was for the DRAC.

> In the BIOS it says I can configure Remote access on [com1] or [com2]
>   not sure if that is ethernet 1 & 2.

It is not. You can use the DRAC to stimulate a serial port.

> I also set it up so to use a static IP adress.

That is the field you want to use.

> That is as far as I have gone. Not sure what to do next.

Connect the DRAC port to the network.
Connect your laptop to the network.
Make sure they are on the same network (same net, different IP)

Now power up the Dell and in a browser on your laptop fill in the DRAC IP in a browser. You will get a webpage with lots of information in the Dell. You can check sensors. Power it off, check the console output etc. Play with it and learn what it can do.

> I have tried to do a PXE server with TFTP but get stuck at Error "cant locate file" 
>   or something like that. Not even sure I want to go that route anymore because of all
>   the hassel of editing files.

You can mount an ISO via the DRAC interface. (well, some of them, not sure if you can do it with the express version of the DRAC). It will appear as a locally mounted CD.

> What steps to I do now?

Reading the manual would be a good start. For me it did a decent job of explaining things (even though the remote volume via DRAC failed miserably when I tried it on anything but a windows running laptop).

One of the steps in the manual should be to configure the DRAC and set up a username and password. The default password should be changed before you connect your sever to a public network, else anyone who can google will discover admin/calvin and will have the option of deleting everything on your computer.

Comment: I was Checking the BIOS and found a option "Set AST2000 LAN Configuration" a quick google search of "AST2000" gave me this [link](http://www.aspeedtech.com/products.php?fPath=20&rId=194) im gonna check it out and update on what I find. Thanks

Comment: I bought this on E-bay for a Home Server and it didn't come with any Doc's. A google search found that the Dell F1D may be a custom build by dell for a big client so not much in the way of Doc's or support.

Comment: Try entering your service tag here: http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/uk/en/ukdhs1/TroubleShooting/ProductSelector  That should show you the system you have, as well as links to drivers and documentation.

Comment: That manual assumes incorrectly that you are not directly reachable from the internet and that you need to work around the problems of NATting. But you do not use NATting, so you do not need to work around it.

Comment: Cool Im at the Embedded Server Manager now. by going to https://static IP address. Really This shit wasn't this easy 10 Years ago. Im gonna log in and find out what This can do.

Comment: Tried to find the service Tag but looks like it got removed.

Comment: Looks like default User/pass was changed gonna try to reset in BIOS

Comment: You might get lucky with booting FreeBSD en running `kenv`, which will show smbios.chassis.serial="SERVICETAG_HERE"

Answer (score 0):

Dells do not have a built in DRAC if you did not order it, it's a  module which must be installed separately.

Comment: Then What is the Remote Access Configuration menu in the BIOS for?

Comment: You have a very basic module that allows you to do stuff like powercycle the machine by sending certain commands to it, but if you want to use the full DRAC, you need to buy the module.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Dell F1D  My suggstion is to puchase a usb cd rom. Boot to the cd rom and install. Needs to be a CD, not DVD. My server will not read DVDs so I am looking for a bios upgrade thru Dell.